# Stripe Checkout I create post/v1/token but no post/v1/paymentintent

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

I am using angular 9 & stripe checkout. I am desperately trying to create a test payment on stripe but I can only send a token to the platform. What should I add?

```
  this.handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    locale: 'auto',
    image:'./assets/images/favicon.png',
    description: 'Boutique créative',
    currency :'eur',
    amount:this.amount * 100,
    token: token => { 
       this.onSave(token.id,
                   token.card.last4,
                   token.client_ip); }});

  this.handler.open({
    name: 'xxxxxx',
    email: this.userToDisplay.email,
    image:'./assets/images/favicon.png',
    description: 'Boutique créative',
    currency :'eur',
    amount: this.amount * 100,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using what is called legacy Checkout, which only creates Tokens.

You should integrate new Checkout: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?integration=checkout

Keep in mind, all Stripe integrations require both web page and server-side code. You create a CheckoutSession on the server, then redirect from your web page.

Comment: Thank you Hmunoz, i was hope that i must just develop on frontend.. but go to node so ;)